# Disable a group of buttons' Interactable state by Tag

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have two groups of buttons on my play area that I'd like to toggle between. I currently have each group tagged differently in the editor and I have another button that I intend to use as the toggle to swap which buttons can be interacted with. Here's what I've got so far, but no luck. I'm getting the error on the IsInteractable line: No overload for method `IsInteractable' takes`1' arguments.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    if(keySet == true)
    {
        // turn ON Interactable for Alpha buttons
        for(int i = 0; i > GameSetup.alphaKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject alphaButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AlphaKey");
            alphaButton.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().IsInteractable(true);
        }

        // turn OFF Interactable for Shape buttons
        for(int i = 0; i > GameSetup.symbolKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject alphaButton = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SymbolKey");
            alphaButton.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().IsInteractable(false);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Do the reverse if false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I added a Canvas Group component to each group of buttons and it made it super easy to control all of the properties I needed to access.

```
public void HandleActiveKeySet (bool keySet)
{
    if(keySet == true)
    {
        GameObject alphaGroup = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AlphaGroup");
        alphaGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = true;
        alphaGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;

        GameObject symbolGroup = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SymbolGroup");
        symbolGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = false;
        symbolGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject alphaGroup = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AlphaGroup");
        alphaGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = false;
        alphaGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;

        GameObject symbolGroup = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SymbolGroup");
        symbolGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = true;
        symbolGroup.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
    }
}
```